# Domain name is disappearing after leaving homepage

Tags: wordpress, apache, dns, virtualhost

I've recently installed a Wordpress on my server.
I'm running Apache and MySQL and the website is working fine.
Things got weird when I tried to linked my domain name to my server's ip.

When I go to mydomain.com, everything's ok but when I go to an other page the URL is now XXX.XXX.XX.XXX/my-article.
So basically, when I go in to a different page than the homepage, the domain name is not used.

Here's the virtualhost I set up (it is in site-enabled after I used a2ensite) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@my-domain.com
        ServerName my-domain.com
        ServerAlias www.my-domain.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/my-domain.com
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
```

And in the domain name manager of my registrar here's what I set-up 
[image: my domain name set-up]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: since you can access the home page using the domain, im going to hazard a guess that you havent updated the site address in wordpress. View the source of the links you are trying to follow, if they are already displaying the domain name correctly, you may have regex matching rules somewhere?

Comment: If you go to the WP database, then to `wp_options` table, what value do you have for `siteurl`? What about `home`?

Comment: When I describe wp_options, there's only 4 fiels : option_id, option_name, option_value and autoload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... In your wordpress admin panel go to settings>permalinks.
set the permalinks to default and save.Now switch back to your desired permalinks format and save again.